# How can I add recalcitrant References to my Windows Store project?

Tags: reference, windows-8, visual-studio-2012, projects-and-solutions, windows-store-apps

I first had a problem with adding a Reference for Bing Maps 
(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13239597/why-can-i-not-reference-bing-maps-in-my-app); but now I realize that I can't even add ANY references.

When I right-click References, I see in the task bar, "This item does not support previewing"; yet the Reference Manager comes up, but clicking on an item (such as "Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Package", or "SQLite for Windows Runtime") does nothing.

Has anybody seen this behavior that knows how to fix it, or at least has any ideas or "hunches" about it?

Here's what I try:

File | New Project | Installed | Templates | Visual C# | Windows Store | Split App (XAML)

The framework selected is ".NET Framework 4.5"

When I expand References, I see:

```
.NET for Windows Store apps
Windows
```

When I right-click References and select Add Reference, the Reference Manager displays with these Windows | Extensions displayed ("*Filtered to: SDKs applicable to* "):

```
Bing Maps for C#, C++, or Visual Basic
Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Packages
Microsoft Visual Studio Test Core
MSTest for Managed Projects
SQLite for Windows Runtime
```

...but selecting any of these and clicking OK does nothing - they are not added to my project's References. To quote the British blokes, "***What the bloody L is going on here?!?***"

### UPDATE

What is happening, too, is that if I select *Tools | Library Package Manager | Manage NuGet Packages for Solution*, when I hover over an item in the list or try to click in the Search edit, the dialog disappears.

Something is obviously *really* wrong here; is it just me? Is anybody else having these problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One must check the checkbox.

So obvious, yet "invisible" to me - it seemed selecting the item should have been enough, and I paid no attention to/didn't "see" the checkbox. Perhaps one shouldn't be allowed to select "OK" with nothing selected/checked? And a hint telling you to check a checkbox?

Here's the answer:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/toolsforwinapps/thread/075ba866-fd8b-41d3-ab5e-a3c0812ab430